# how to configure jenkins by invoking ant and build a job?

Tags: xml, ant, jenkins

In the jenkins configure project, i have the build step "Invoke Ant".

I have a build.xml file in a specific path and this xml file has import tags which imports two other xml files which are in the same path.

My job is getting failed because it is unable to find the files to be imported. I'm getting the error like "cannot find abc/def/xyz.xml"

I have given the build.xml file path in the "build file" column.

1. What should I type in the properties column and java options column?
2. How to give path for the other two files which needs to be imported by build.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** Make sure all files are relative to Jenkins workspace

**Option 2.** Hard-code the files' path in your `build.xml`

**Option 3.** Setup a property for the path of those files in your `build.xml`. Give that property a default value of whatever the path is right now (to make sure it still works without Jenkins). When invoking from Jenkins, in the properties field, enter the property name with a value for the absolute path that should be reachable.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have imported the main-script.xml file as : <import file="${dir.base}/_ant/_build/main-script.xml"/>. But the build is still failing in Jenkins. Any solution for this?